# Watching full-screen videos using C# Web Browser

Tags: c#, visual-studio, video, youtube

I'm currently working with Visual Studio and Windows Forms. I want to be able to watch full-screen videos from sources such as Youtube and Vimeo.

I am attempting to do this with a Web Browser but I get issues where the web browser opens YouTube and attempts to download something and Vimeo reports that there could be an issue and refuses to play the video. I already know the URL's of each video as they are responses to inputs.

What would be the best way to watch videos using a Windows Form?

At the moment I am currently just using;

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.youtube.com")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was plagued with the issue that my browser did not support HTML5, although I had IE 11 installed and it did not go away.

I found that using a Shockwave Flash Object was the best method to display movies/youtube videos. I simply added the component to the form and entered the desired movie and worked as intended, I'll use web browsers for non-media content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed the video on a web browser control...
check out the following thread on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/27c17127-b447-419e-8dd7-7ef8a8d4c16e/help-embedding-a-youtube-video-into-a-windows-form?forum=vbgeneral)